# Combine multiple external APIs in one

Tags: oop, design-patterns, laravel

So again I have a question.

I need to access several APIs (SOAP, REST) for which I've created or downloaded packages. Well, every API returns the data I need in it's own way so I want to create a class for every API with the same methods that output the data exactly how I need it. So I think creating an interface would be right because every class should have the same methods.

Now the question:

Let's assume I have a method called *getAllMovies()* in the interface. Now I want to call this method either like *getAllMovies($APItoUse)* or *getAllMovies()*. Without param I'd like to get the movies from all avialable APIs.

What would be the best way to do this? Should I create something like a class that knows all the APIs that I use and then calls the method in every API I need, merges the outputs together and returns it?

I think there are a few ways to do this but I'm asking because I'd like to make it the right way.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build an array with your api's names and iterate it. Once inside the bucle you could execute a case sentence and depending on which api are you in, instance an object of a class or another. Then simply call the method you need.

```
$apis = array('api1','api2',...);
$allMovies = array();
foreach($apis as $api){
    switch($api){
        case 'api1': $obj = new API1Class; break;
        case 'api2': $obj = new API2Class; break;
        ...
    }
    array_push($allMovies,$obj->getAllMovies());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is how I thought of doing it. Because there are more methods for each API I'd do best if I make a class out of your example above and create one method for each API method which then decides what API to use, right? I thought that there is maybe a better pattern but it looks like I was right :)